# Curses.getstr cleans windows on the first call

Tags: ruby, curses

The first `Curses.getstr` call clears another window. On later calls it doesn't happen.

```
require "curses"

Curses.init_screen

window = Curses::Window.new(10, 10, 5, 0)
window.scrollok true

Thread.new do
    loop do
        window.addstr rand(1000000).to_s
        window.refresh
        sleep 0.1
    end
end

Curses.setpos 20, 0
sleep 1
# now several lines of numbers suddenly disappear
loop{ Curses.getstr }
```

How can I fight this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is an implicit `refresh()` of the stdscr window -- because `getstr()` is really `wgetstr(stdscr)`. Your options include:

1. Manually refreshing stdscr before drawing anything
2. Using your new window for input, rather than stdscr, and/or
3. Using stdscr for output.

At least, that's the answer I'd give for curses' native C -- I'm not sure how it translates to Ruby.